# How could I code a bar with 3 circles spaced out evenly on the bar with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to display a line at the bottom on my website with three circles at the bottom so that the first is on the left, the second is in the middle and the third is on the right. how could I do this using CSS?

Comment: How do you want the circles to look? Like images, text, or other?

Comment: Are you asking how to make a line and 3 circles? You could make a PNG or an SVG or a CSS only solution.

Comment: An `SVG` image will stretch over every screen size with a `width: 100%;`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I made this with CSS,

**CSS**

```
.lineB {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}

.lineL {
  height: 2px;
  background: #2b2b2b;
  width: 45%;
  top: 25px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

.lineR {
  height: 2px;
  background: #2b2b2b;
  width: 45%;
  top: 25px;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

.circles {
  width: 118px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.circle {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #2b2b2b;
}

.C {
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 2.5em;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="lineB">
<span class="lineL"></span>
<span class="lineR"></span>
<div class="circles">
    <span class="circle"></span>
    <span class="circle C"></span>
    <span class="circle"></span>
</div>
```

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/EPHxb/) That will show how it looks.

I would *HIGLY* recommend that you just make an `SVG` (Scalable Vector Graphic) image for better flexibility.

`SVG` Image files are amazingly flexible and will stretch over any and every screen size.

Comment: True, but imo, its a bit of a "overkill" for just 3 circles; i'd use svgs for big picture stuff

Comment: @Crispy-George I agree 100% on that, all that code for such a minor element on the page. `SVG` images are were it is at. :p

Answer (score 1):

Hy user2961662,

I would use of pseudo-classes, as its the fastest way to do it:

```
element:after{}
element:before{}
```

It really comes down to what you actually need; go ahead and see my example bellow,

[check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/Jre8C/)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the canvas object (HTML5) - it has been made to allow for a lot of things to do with graphics. Tutorial on HTML5 canvas can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp). Additionally, you could find a link more specific to circles [here](https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-circles/&ei=vIt9UsnjAYWKkwWjuYHoDA&usg=AFQjCNHc0Rl4GGsEtEs_49mLWbV7GoY3rQ&sig2=Lq87RAFOFHvwIkv1EvN49Q&bvm=bv.56146854,d.dGI). For the line, if you do not want to use the canvas, could be done easily with a border outline.